# Can a SQL Server query return or C# generate newline delimited json?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to return a data set from a SQL Server stored procedure where output should look like newline delimited json. How can I achieve this?

```
SELECT [ID],[Name]
FROM [tbl_sample]
FOR JSON PATH, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
```

If it is not possible from SQL Server end directly, is it possible from C#?

I mean, I need to create each SQL select dataTable to generate individual ND-JSON file in the directory.

Could you please share your thoughts it would be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: JSON is generally a data interchange format. Systems that use JSON don't care if it's formatted or not. If this is for a user visualisation, do it in the visualisation tool (C#). It is possible to inject carriage returns into strings in T-SQL. Please post a sample of what you want your data to look like

Comment: Since NDJSON isn't really JSON you'll have to handle the differences yourself. By that I mean that although each root-level object is indeed JSON format the root-level objects themselves are separated from each other by newline characters instead of comma characters. You could simulate that yourself by JSON encoding each `tbl_sample` record in a subquery, so if there were eight records you'd return eight separate JSON snippets, then on the C# side you'd concatenate the JSON snippets together with newline characters.

Comment: Hi @Nick.McDermaid, Actually I have almost ~1Million records of each dataTable now i need to generate new line delimited json file in the directory. What would be the most suitable and fast way to do this in c# or sql server end?

Answer (score 1):

You can put each row in a subquery to create its JSON individually, then aggregate it using new-lines using `STRING_AGG`:

```sql
SELECT STRING_AGG(j.json, N'
') AS json
FROM [tbl_sample]
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT [ID],[Name]
    FOR JSON PATH, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
) j(json);
```

Alternatively you can return each row individually:

```sql
SELECT
  (
    SELECT [ID],[Name]
    FOR JSON PATH, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
  ) AS json
FROM [tbl_sample];
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=60dc1235c8d1e4d2687279582a406dd0)